# SharePoint restoring .bak file got failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I tried to restore .bak file and it failed due to "Restore-SPSite : Access is denied. (Exception from HResult: 0x00070005 (E_AccessDenied))"

And now, site colletion is down and shows page not found. How to make it up, thanks.

Comment: To restore a site collection, user must be site collection administrator. Is your user is site collection admin?

Comment: Yes, but now i want to make site collection up immediately. How to do? thanks

Comment: Please make sure that the user id your'e using to take the back up and restore being the site collection administrator on both the sites.

Answer (score 0):

To restore a site collection, user **must be site collection administrator**. Please check to see if the current user SharePoint Farm administrator.

This user must be a member of the following groups:

- Administrators
- WSS_ADMIN_WPG
- WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG

**Add user to SharePoint Shell access**

Run below command:(Change user name and your db name)

```
Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.Name -eq "WSS_Content"} | Add-SPShellAdmin -Username CONTOSO\User1
```

**Grant permission on site to your current user:**

```
$w = get-spwebapplication http://[urltodestinationwebapp]
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("[domain\curretusername]")
```

**Grant Permissions on SQL DB**

- Grant the current user  **DB_Owner** DB role of the relevant content database.
- Grant the current user the fixed server role: **securityadmin**.

**Reference:**

- [Restore backup from one farm to another in same domain: Access Denied](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145722/restore-backup-from-one-farm-to-another-in-same-domain-access-denied)